# How do I create a stacked EMAs alert in tradingview using the code from tos listed below? I can't figure out how to convert it to pinescript

Tags: pine-script, thinkscript

```
input length1 = 8;
input length2 = 21;
input length3 = 34;
input length4 = 55;
input length5 = 89;
input displace = 0;
 
def ema8 = ExpAverage(close, 8);
def ema21 = ExpAverage(close, 21);
def ema34 = ExpAverage(close, 34);
def ema55 = ExpAverage(close, 55);
def ema89 = ExpAverage(close, 89);
   
def price = close;
        
plot EMA8_ = ExpAverage(close, 8);
plot EMA21_ = ExpAverage(close, 21);
plot EMA34_ = ExpAverage (close, 34);
plot EMA55_ = ExpAverage (close, 55);
plot EMA89_ = ExpAverage (close, 89);
  
AddLabel(close, ”Stacked EMAs” , (if price > ema89 and price > ema55 and price > ema34 and price > ema21 and price > ema8 then Color.GREEN else Color.RED));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code inside code blocks and see the guide on how to ask questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
study("Help (TOS)", overlay=true)

length1 = input(8,  'length1')
length2 = input(21, 'length2')
length3 = input(34, 'length3')
length4 = input(55, 'length4')
length5 = input(89, 'length5')

ema1 = ema(close, length1)
ema2 = ema(close, length2)
ema3 = ema(close, length3)
ema4 = ema(close, length4)
ema5 = ema(close, length5)
 
plot(ema1, color=color.green)
plot(ema2, color=color.yellow)
plot(ema3, color=color.red)
plot(ema4, color=color.purple)
plot(ema5, color=color.black)

plot(close, color=color.blue, linewidth=2)

stack = close > ema5 and close > ema4 and close > ema3 and close > ema2 and close > ema1
plotshape(true, text="Stacked EMAs", textcolor=stack ? color.green : color.red, show_last=1)
```

[image]